# How can I import images from another folder?

Tags: html, vue.js

so I wanted to know if it's possible to import images from a different folder. My images are in my other folder named server and I wanted to display them in my client page. Before I was using image from URL but now it's in my folder. I am using Vue.js. I need to get the images in this path : "VueProject/router/uploads/publication.userPicture"

I am currently in this path : VueProject/project/src/views/marketl

```html
 <img v-bind:src="publication.userPicture" height="48px" width="48px">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that this other folder is public to the web and that all the pictures are in the same folder, you can just add the relative path in front of the bound value:

```js
<img :src="'/path/to/other/folder/' + publication.userPicture">
```

If you have different folders for different types of images or other context, you can set the path in a computed and use that as your bound value in the template.  Again, the path you generate here needs to be public to the web:

```js
computed: {
  imgSrc() {
    // assuming folder names based on some other context
    switch ( this.someContextVar ) {
      case 'a':
        return '/path/to/a/context/' + this.publication.userPicture;
      case 'b':
        return '/path/to/b/context/' + this.publication.userPicture;
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

```js
<img :src="imgSrc">
```

Comment: Thank you but the image doesn't show. In my html page I can see in the HTML "src="/server/uploads/IMG_20200813_0006.jpg"

Comment: If you see that in the generated HTML source, the code is working as expected.  Make sure the folder is publicly accessible to the web and that the file exists.